# htop showing less memory usage

Tags: monitoring, ram, ramdisk

I'm currently trying to benchmark performance improvements when using a RAM disk. So I've been giving my VM 24 of the total 32 GB RAM, and created a 16GB RAM Disk inside. It's beeing used, approximately it's filled with 8 GB. Additionally there are compilers and test running, so the overall memory usage of the VM should be quite high. Still, when looking in htop, it shows me there are only 5GB used (which is not much more than in average, without running the VM), while the process indicates there are 25GB in use.

Do I missunderstand the htop display? I thought just the green part of the Mem bar represents actual used RAM, while the yellow part is reserved for caching and stuff? So my expectation was there should be not much less than 30GB RAM used. Even when looking at the actual used memory in the process list, which seems to indicate that not used RAM DISK space isn't allocated in RAM, there is still a value way higher then the overall used...

[image: HTOP output]